# Jenkins: The result file for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped

Tags: xml, maven, junit, jenkins

I am getting this error when Jenkins tries to read the result xml file through Junit

this is the output

```
> [xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing JUnit
[xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern '**\testResults\*.xml' relative to 'C:\Jenkins\jobs\InstantMatcher\workspace' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The result file 'C:\Jenkins\jobs\InstantMatcher\workspace\Code\RegressionTest\testResults\result-InstantMatcher - Copy.xml' for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Fail BUILD because 'set build failed if errors' option is activated.
[xUnit] [INFO] - There are errors when processing test results.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping tests recording.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stop build.
Finished: FAILURE
```

My XML file looks like this

```
 <testsuite failures="0" tests="209" name="UnitTests.MainClassTest">
    <testcase classname="UnitTests.OSUtils" name="stripExtension" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="0.03 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.OSUtils" name="changeExtension" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="0.04 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.OSUtils" name="stripPathAndExtension" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="0.04 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.OSUtils" name="getFilename" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="0.03 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.OSUtils" name="atoi" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="0.47 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.CImage" name="jpg matches bmp" parameters="" assertions="pass" time="N/A"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Bandpass Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Orientation Dominance Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Saliency MapSync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Level Keypoints Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Bandpass Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Orientation Dominance Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Saliency MapSync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Level Keypoints Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Bandpass Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Orientation Dominance Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Saliency MapSync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Test Level Keypoints Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
        <testcase classname="UnitTests.InstantMatcher" name="Bandpass Sync: " parameters="" assertions="pass" time="109.73 ms"/>
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 12):

There are numerous bugs in the Jenkins bug tracker regarding xUnit parsing failures with various JUnit-like output. xUnit is great if you're using one of the formats it understands, but it's less good for parsing generic JUnit-like output generated by a non-JUnit tool. In my experience, you're better off using the built in *Publish JUnit test results report* post-build action.

[JENKINS-18095](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18095) has a pointer to the [XSD](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/dtkit/dtkit-format/dtkit-junit-model/src/main/resources/com/thalesgroup/dtkit/junit/model/xsd/junit-7.xsd) that xUnit uses to validate the JUnit XML. Based on that, I would guess that the `parameters` attribute in your `testcase` element is tripping up the xUnit validation.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I solved my problem by downgrading the xUnit plugin, so maybe there is a bug in the latest plugin?

Comment: Which version exactly You downgraded to?