# Jenkins: The result file for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped. Report Contains Invalid XML

Tags: junit, jenkins

I am getting this error when Jenkins tries to read the result xml file through Junit

this is the output

> ```
> > 12:47:46 D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SentraSAHI\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Chrome>exit
> > 0  
> > 12:47:46 [xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record. 
> > 12:47:46 [xUnit] [INFO] - Processing JUnit 
> > 12:47:46 [xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'SentraIntegrationTesting\SahiJUnitResults\TEST-*.xml' relative to 'D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SentraSAHI\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Chrome' for the testing framework 'JUnit'. 
> > 12:47:47 [xUnit] [ERROR] - The result file 'D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SentraSAHI\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Chrome\SentraIntegrationTesting\SahiJUnitResults\TEST-Sentra_ExternalUrls_chrome.xml'
> > for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
> > 12:47:47 [xUnit] [INFO] - Failing BUILD because 'set build failed if errors' option is activated. 
> > 12:47:47 [xUnit] [INFO] - There are errors when processing test results. 
> > 12:47:47 [xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping tests recording. 
> > 12:47:47 [xUnit] [INFO] - Stop build.
> > 12:47:47 Build step 'Publish xUnit test result report' changed build
> > result to FAILURE
> ```

My XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="Sentra_IntegrationTests.suite.Sentra_ExternalUrls" tests="1" time="173.162">
<testcase classname="Sentra_IntegrationTests.suite.Sentra_ExternalUrls" name="Sentra_ExternalUrls.sah" time="173.162">499Sentra_IntegrationTests__14Aug2014__02_14_57_872Sentra_IntegrationTests.suiteD:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SENTRASAHIO\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Oracle-Firefox\SentraIntegrationTesting/SahiScripts/Sentra_IntegrationTests.suite2014-08-14 02:14:57.8712014-08-14 05:19:56.273FAILURE4440411098402null
a=a
baseURL=http://SENTRASAHIO.TEST.LOCAL:8080/Sentra_Latest_Sources_MasterBuild_Oracle_Console/SentraSahi.html?locale=sq
browserOption=-profile C:\Progra~1\sahiPRO\userdata\browser\ff\profiles\sahi0 -no-remote
browserPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
browserProcessName=firefox.exe
emailProp=
host=localhost
logsInfo=html:D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SENTRASAHIO\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Oracle-Firefox\SentraIntegrationTesting\target\IntegrationTestResults\Sentra-Latest_Sources-2014-08-13_19-01-21_Build_520_all\2014-08-14_02-14-57,junit:D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SENTRASAHIO\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Oracle-Firefox\SentraIntegrationTesting\SahiJUnitResults
port=9999
sahisid=sahi_b2763f4a05c8b04ec70a774077f99cdaf13d
suiteId=sahi_b2763f4a05c8b04ec70a774077f99cdaf13d
suiteName=Sentra_IntegrationTests.suite
suitePath=D:\BuildShare\HudsonSlave_SENTRASAHIO\workspace\SentraIntegrationTesting-LS-Oracle-Firefox\SentraIntegrationTesting/SahiScripts/Sentra_IntegrationTests.suite
suiteReportId=Sentra_IntegrationTests__14Aug2014__02_14_57_872
threads=1null000
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Any ideas please?
Thanks
Donna

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so going to answer.  It looks like there's an explanation on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138228/jenkins-the-result-file-for-the-metric-junit-is-not-valid-the-result-file-ha)

> There are numerous bugs in the Jenkins bug tracker regarding xUnit parsing failures with various JUnit-like output. xUnit is great if you're using one of the formats it understands, but it's less good for parsing generic JUnit-like output generated by a non-JUnit tool. In my experience, you're better off using the built in Publish JUnit test results report post-build action.
>
> JENKINS-18095 has a pointer to the XSD that xUnit uses to validate the JUnit XML. Based on that, I would guess that the parameters attribute in your testcase element is tripping up the xUnit validation.
>
> [Dave Bacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172599/dave-bacher)

reponse

> Thanks @Dave, I solved my problem by downgrading the xUnit plugin, so maybe there is a bug in the latest plugin? –  user2043042 Oct 3 '13 at 11:33